# apply html5 tag "required" to every browsers

Tags: html

in html5, there is tag "required" for input,

eg:`<input type="text" required="required" value="" />`

but it is working on Firefox,Opera and Chrome, but not for IE and Safari, i tried to include `<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>`,  but it is still not working !

Comment: All html5 shiv does is add support for elements that do not exist in old browsers (this mostly only affects IE8-) and is really only useful for styling.

Comment: i used, but it is not working in Safari

Comment: You seem to have ignored what I said.  `html5shiv` doesn't make `required` work.  Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Explosion Pills mentioned in [his comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289129/apply-html5-tag-required-to-every-browsers#comment23316133_16289129), the [`required` form attribute is not supported by Safari or versions of Internet Explorer lower than 10](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#required).

You can get around this by using a third-party JavaScript plugin that will enforce form validation regardless of browser version. See https://github.com/dilvie/h5Validate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use html5shiv to add require.

Try something like this (uses JQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/DfCHu/

```
$('form').submit(function() { 

    var empty_fields = $('input').filter(function() {

        //return empty required fields
        return $(this).attr("required") && $(this).val() === "";

    });

    // if empty required field stop the form submitting and let the user know
    if(empty_fields.length){
        alert('something required');
        return false; 
    }

});
```